# Fetching data by id React + Flask

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the details by id from Flask db by fetching.
My React code

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("fetching")
    //const record = new FormData();
    //record.append("id", 7);
    fetch('/getMetaReport', {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'},
    }).then(response => {
      return console.log(response)
    })
```

My Flask code

```
@app.route("/getMetaReport", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getReports():
    req = flask.request.get_json(force=True)
    user_id = req.get('id', None)
    raw_reports = Report.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()

    metas = []
    for r in raw_reports:
        metas.append(r.get_meta())

    return jsonify(metas), 200
```

I don't know how to get the details by id from Flask to React. It gives me 400 error already.

Comment: Hello Beyza , Welcome to StackOverflow. From your question it is not clear what problem is.
Please do update your question with more details such as what is the expected result or what is the error you received that is blocking you from completing this and we will be able to help you more

Answer (score 0):

English Below
Selam Beyza, Flask tarafında get isteğinde bir id geleceğini söylüyorsun lakin react tarafında bir id göndermiyorsun gibi görünüyor.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
        id: 1
      }),
```

gibi bir kodu headers satırının altına eklemeni rica edeceğim.

English Hi Beyza, On the flask side, you say you will get an id in the get request, but it seems like you are not sending an id on the react side.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
            id: 1
          }),
```

I will ask you to add a code such as under the headers line.

Comment: Yaptım fakat console da response'u göremiyorum nasıl bastırabilirim

Comment: Hata yok ama response'u da göremiyorsun sanırım ? Flask tarafında return'dan önce print edip bakar mısın ? O tarafta istediğin gibi bir sonuç geliyor mu ? Eğer o kısımda sorun yok ise return olarak bir obje dönmeyi deneyebilirsin return { "data" : jsonify(metas) , "code" : 200 } gibi ve response.data şeklinde console'a bastırırsın.

Comment: Flask'ta print ettiriyorum onda sıkıntı yok. Fakat React kısmında console'a bastırırken sıkıntı çıkıyor. Aslında hata vermiyor fakat bastıramıyor. return { "data" : jsonify(metas) , "code" : 200 } bu dediğinizi react'e nasıl uyarlayabilirim

Comment: Flask için : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8jhkvCVYmz/
React için : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/QPC5PrMhXZ/

Flask kısmında request kısmında hata alırsan
from flask import Flask, request 
kodunu eklersin yani request'di de import edersin.

Comment: Ah tamam şimdi çözdüm console'da görebiliyorum. Yardımlarınız için teşekkür ederim. Gönüllü olursanız diğer React + Flask'la ilgili sorumda da yardım etmek isterseniz çok mutlu olurum.

Comment: oguzzhanakinci@gmail.com mail adresim. Elimden geldiğince yardımcı olmaya çalışırım. Mail üzerinden iletişim kurabiliriz. Yada tercih edeceğiniz başka bir iletişim yolunu mail atabilirsiniz. İyi Çalışmalar.